# SSRS Connection Properties for Hyperion Essbase

Tags: oracle, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, database-connection, essbase

I use the Excel Add-Ins feature to do pulls from Essbase. Logging in through Excel I have my Server, Application and Database. When trying to set up a data source via SSRS I have to enter Server Name, Analytic Server to Use and Application Name.

1. Is the Server and Application the exact same between the Excel Add-Ins & SSRS? When I put the server from the Excel Add-In in the SSRS Server name box the user name and password is still greyed out. But when I start the SSRS server name with "http://", I'm able to enter my user name and password. Is there any way to find out the rest of http:// without having to go through our Essbase team?
2. How do I find my Analytic Server? I get it should probably drop down if I have the server name correct, but how do I find out if we even have an analytic server set up for SSRS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your Analytic server should be the same as the one you use to connect to via the Excel add-in / Smartview.

Your connection string would look something like this:

Data Source=http://servername:portnumber/aps/XMLA;Initial Catalog=ApplicationName;DataSourceInfo="Provider=Essbase;Data Source=essbaseservername"